# How do I find the volume of this region?

Tags: multiple-integral

The solid sphere $\{ (x,y,z)\in R^3 ; x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1\}$ is cut into two parts by the plane $z=\frac{1}{2}$. I’m required to find the volume of the smaller part. 
I know how to do double and triple integrals essentially. But I have difficulty visualising problems like this. How do I proceed here?

Edit: I also want to do similar problems, so if anyone can link me to an article/site explaining relevant theory,do post it.

Comment: That would be great,thank you.

Comment: You might consider [Triple Integrals for the Sketching Impaired](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07468342.2017.1394669?journalCode=ucmj20).

Comment: Draw a cross section on the $xz$-plane. The sphere will look like a circle of radius $1$, and the cut $z=\frac12$ will just be a horizontal line.

Comment: One place to start is to visualize a sphere cut in half by the $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an image of the whole situation:

[image: Sphere with plane]

The $xy$-plane is in gray, the $z = \frac12$ plane is in blue. We want the volume of the top part.

There are several ways to do this. Mainly we need to choose a coordinate system. I'll go with Cartesian, because of its familiarity, but it's probably actually most convenient to do this in cylindrical coordinates (e.g. see it as a solid of rotation about the $z$-axis). Spherical coordinates are made slightly tricky by the $z = \frac12$ plane, but that's not entirely impossible either.

(Most of the time, choosing a coordinate system so that the relevant region is nicely presentable more than outweighs the possibly more inconvenient form of the volume element. Respect the symmetry you're given, and you are generally rewarded. In this case, it is simple enough for me to refrain, though.)

So, in Cartesian coordinates, I believe the most convenient way is to do $z$-integral outermost. The plane makes $z = \frac12$ a very nice and natural lower bound for the entire thing, and the upper bound must be $z = 1$. So, what needs integrating with respect to $z$ here? Since we're after a volume, integrating a function $A(z)$ that yields an area for each value of $z$ is very natural.

And the most natural area for any given $z$-value is the cross-sectional area of the sphere, which is to say, the area of a certain circle. Imagine a plane in my picture, parallel to the blue one, moving from the blue one up to the top of the sphere. The cross section between that and the sphere is what we're integrating.

This gives
$$
V_{\text{upper}} = \int_{1/2}^1A(z)\,dz
$$
So, what is this area function? Well, for any given $z$ value, the radius of the cross-section circle is $\sqrt{1-z^2}$. And the area of a circle with that radius is $\pi(1-z^2)$. So that's what we get:
$$
V_{\text{upper}} = \int_{1/2}^1\pi(1-z^2)\,dz = \pi\left(1 - \frac13\right) - \pi\left(\frac12 - \frac1{24}\right)\\
= \frac{5\pi}{24}
$$

Comment: This cleared up a great deal. Only thing is (I’m sure it’s a clear answer but I’m not getting it)— when I cut the sphere at $z=\frac{1}{2}$, the cross section seems to be a circle with equation $x^2+y^2=1$,with a thickness $dz$. I am unable to understand how you got $\sqrt{1-z^2}$.

Comment: @user733666 The boundary of the cross section at any fixed $z$-value is still given by $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$, which is to say $x^2+y^2 = 1-z^2$, which gives a circle of radius $\sqrt{1-z^2}$. For instance, at the blue plane ($z = \frac12$), the cross-section is the circle given by $x^2+y^2 = 1-\frac14$, which gives a radius of $\frac{\sqrt3}2$.

Comment: Ah,I’m embarrassed I asked that now. Nevertheless,thank you for taking the time out to give the picture. I have an exam in two days and this has helped me out.

Comment: @user733666 No worries. And remember, if the region is somewhat more complicated, the $A(z)$ function (or maybe it's $A(y)$ or $A(x)$, it all depends on what's convenient) might itself be best to calculate by using an integral. In this case, we might have had $A(z)=\int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\ell(y, z)\,dy$, where $\ell(y,z)$ is the length of the line segment inside the sphere at the given $y$ and $z$ coordinates. So we get $$V_{\text{upper}} = \int_{1/2}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \ell(y, z)\,dy\,dz$$And that's all there is to double integrals. Looks scary, but really isn't.

Comment: It does scare me when I don’t get it,but once I can *see* it, it’s quite amazing. How do you create the images? Is there any site that helps to do this?

Comment: @user733666 That image is made with a piece of graphing software called GeoGebra. Another popular one I've seen people use from time to time is Desmos, although I am not very familiar with it myself and don't know whether it has 3D capabilities. As for calculating multiple integrals, setting them up is about doing them one at a time, from the outside in, like I described in my previous comment, and calculating them is about doing them one at a time, from the inside out. Always a single 1-dimensional integral at a time. "Simultaneous integration" is a theoretical thing, not for calculations.

Comment: Outside in, and Inside out. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It this case you can observe that you want to compute the volume of a solid of revolution, which is in given by
$$
\int_{1/2}^{1} \pi (\sqrt{1-z^2})^2 du = \pi[z-\frac 12 z^2]_{1/2}^{1}=\frac{5 \pi}{24}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The volume is a spherical cap with the base circle given by $ x^2+y^2 = 1-\frac1{2^2} = \frac34$. Then, integrate the volume in cylindrical coordinates with $z(r) = \sqrt{1-r^2}$ and the limits 
$r \le\frac{\sqrt3}2$ and $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$.

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt3/2} (z(r)-\frac12)rdrd\theta
=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt3/2} (\sqrt{1-r^2}-\frac12)rdr=\frac{5\pi}{24}$$